# Is it practical to use the person's ID card as a primary key?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, primary-key, convention

I'm working on a project and I usually use the person's ID as a primary key to identify the person. But right now I'm working on something much more formal and serious then what I've been working on... (School DB) Is it good practice to use the person's/student's ID card instead of having another field (ID) auto generated/sequence as a PK.

Comment: It's up to you. You decide on your requirements, and therefore you decide if your proposal meets your requirements. Does it need to be unique? Can you guarantee they will always be unique? (be sure you can do this) If yes to both, then should be fine. Though there is no harm in having an auto 'ID' field anyway

Comment: Natural vs surrogate key is a long debate, pick one.I think in your case there is little advantage of one option over another.Surrogate key might be a little faster since its made of integers starting with 1

Comment: Thanks for the quick response people, Yes I'm going to use the student's ID's ad the primary key, the auto generated field is not quite necessary in this case because all the students ID's are unique

Comment: What happens when a student loses their ID card?  Are they issued with a new ID, or do they get a new card with their old ID on it?  I'd probably use that to control what to do.  If the new card has a new ID, you shouldn't use the card ID number to identify the person; it identifies their card, not the person.  If the new card is (normally) reissued with the same ID, then it might be OK to use the ID number — I would probably, but not necessarily, avoid using the card ID number as the person's ID number even so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look after a similar student database and we use student ids as PK.

It helps us because students are aware of their IDs and if they have any issues they can come to us and quote their ID for us to resolve the issue. It certainly makes it easier than trudging through a load of John Smiths.

The down side I have found is that we do export data to programs such as excel and alot of the IDs have leading zeros which if you are not careful will be removed.

It is entirely up to you, but in my opinion I would use them.

Comment: That's the way I'm going for, basically using an auto generated number over a student's unique ID number as PK is not quite efficient in my case as the Student's ID is a perfect candidate for the Primary Key :) Thank you for your opinion

Comment: You shouldn't. The primary key should always be an autonumber ID except for very rare cases and this is not one of these.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bad idea, for one simple reason:  security.

You are better off designing your databases to have internal ids for all entities.  The person's id would then be an attribute on the records, rather than a primary key.  This allows you, for instance, to encrypt the id (and other sensitive information).  If someone gets a hold of a print-out of some data, you don't have to worry that they are seeing personal information.

In the United States, this design is helped by the fact that social security numbers -- the closest thing we have to a national id -- were specifically designed not to be national id numbers.  Apart from the issue of fraud, the approximately one billion numbers will run out one day.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up mate !

Comment: What makes you think that US SSNs are not guaranteed to be unique over time? Note that SSNs are not recycled and never have been according to the SSA. Rumours to the contrary appear to be no more than just rumour.

Comment: @sqlvogel . . . I rephrased that to be more accurate.

Comment: Will they run out? When they've used 1 billion numbers maybe the SSA will just put a 1 in front of future numbers. Changes to requirements are always possible in any system. On the same basis we wouldn't use "internal" id's either because *one day* (probably a lot sooner than SSNs run out) you'll be asked to redesign/replace the database and change it.

Comment: @sqlvogel . . . It is less that they are currently re-used then the fact that the legislation implementing them explicitly stated that they should not be used as an id for individuals.  That would seem to make it dangerous, without other identifying information (and that is leaving aside the problem of fraudulent re-use of social security numbers).